# Come back to fragment, Android

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity called MainActivity with 2 fragment (let's call them A and B). This activity shows A on the left and B on the right in case of large display, but, for small display, there is only one frameLayout and I change the fragment in it after I clicked something in the fragment B.
So, for small device, I show initially fragment A and from it I can go to B, (I select a day from my CalendarView in fragment A and then I can go to B).
In B then I can go to another Activity by clicking a button. From that activity I want to came back to my previously activity but I don't know how to have the fragment B already inflated. Right now if I go back to my MainActivity I find fragment A also if I left this activity with B inflated.
I can come back either with the back button on my actionbar or after I close my last activity (the one I go after B).
Can anyone help me?
This is the Main activity class in which I have the two fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CalendarFragment.OnCalendarSelectedListener{
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar=getSupportActionBar();

        if(findViewById(R.id.left_fragment) != null){
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            AFragment leftFragment = new AFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.left_fragment, leftFragment).commit();
        }
        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.right_fragment) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
                // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
                BFragment bFragment = new BFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.add(R.id.right_fragment, bFragment).commit();


        }
    }
...
//this is how I inflate the fragment B from a click on fragment A
    public void onCalendarSelected(int day, int month, int year) {

        BFragment bFragment = (BFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.right_fragment);


             if (bFragment != null) {

            bFragment.updateList(day);
        } else {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            BFragment newFragment = new BFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("day",day);

            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            transaction.replace(R.id.left_fragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

This code works fine but I don't know how to solve my problem.